# How to extend POCO generated by Reverse POCO Generator?

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, poco, partial-classes

I used Reverse POCO Generator to generate pocos for my project (partial classes) .

Then, I extended one of my pocos by creating a new partial class (new file) with the same class name and in the same namespace. I added new property, for example:

```
public int NewProperty { get; set; }
```

Now, the problem is, when I query database, I see that new property is included in my DBContext. I see select statement like: SELECT Field1, Field2, **NewProperty** FROM MyDatabase.

And of course, I get following error: *SqlClientException: Invalid column name 'NewProperty'* as this field doesn't exist.

**How can I stop DBContext from including my new property in database operations?** I did this on my previous projects and had no issues (used edmx models).

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using Entity Framework, you can make it ignore a property by adding the `NotMapped` attribute, like so:

```
[NotMapped]
public int NewProperty { get; set; }
```

This can also be set in fluent API if you prefer, it should be something like this for EF Core:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<YourClass>().Ignore(t => t.NewProperty);
```

Comment: Thank you so much. That worked. I wonder I I got through before without using this.